# How to apply Default wallpaper to clients in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have one Dell poweredge 1850 server running on server 2012.

I installed ADDS and Make one OU in it then i make users (approx 20) and then move all users to OU.

But know when i tried to manage the default wallpaper policy from GPMGMT. that wallpaper only apply on server..not on client pc..client pc shows black screen only..plz help

Comment: Have you actually joined the client PCs to Active Directory?

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly a file permission problem on the wallpaper image file, or the wallpaper image file not being on the workstations or accessible to them via a network share.